# Creating Virtual Device without writing to Uinput Module.

Tags: android, virtual, emulation

Is there any other way to create a Virtual Device such as Virtual Mouse,etc without the opening the uinput module as WRONLY and writing to it.

I am asking because certain Android OEM's are preventing writing to Uinput even with Root privileges and correct permissions by setting SELinux in enforcing mode.

If there is any other way to create Virtual device without Uinput,even that solution would do.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.